# Problema con nombre de tabla e id en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, crud

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Intento hacer un crud con laravel  5.6 y con tabla llamada t_areaFuncional pero mi modelo es AreaFuncional y mi controlador AreaFuncionaController, desactive .. la convencion que tiene laravel. con respecto a las migraciones ... mi tabla en la base de datos se llama "t_areaFuncional" pero laravel genera por defecto la consulta "select * from `t_areafuncional` where `id`"

[image: como ven hasta ahi todo bien]

[image: y este es el controlador AreaFuncionalController@show]

[image: Esto en Diseño de Platillas show.blade.php]

[image: por que me sale este error al querer ver los campos de la tabla t_areafuncional NO ENTIENDO POR ME SALE ESTA CONSULTA SI deberia salir la consulta select * from <code>t_areafuncional</code> where <code>idAreaFuncional</code> .. como lo hago ...]

[image: y esta es mi ruta]

Comment: me parece que la propiedad para declarar el id es $primaryKey sin espacios y la segunda palabra inicia en mayúscula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acuerdo a la documentación de Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent

La declaración de la propiedad que va a sobreescribir la forma en que por defecto Eloquent busca usar una llave primaria que es solo por el nombre de `id` se debe declarar así

```
protected $primaryKey = 'idAreaFuncional';
```

> También toma en cuenta que Laravel asumirá que dicha llave primaria es
>   auto incremental y de tipo `INT/BIGINT`según sea el caso

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo ... me ayudo, una consulta mas como hago para declarar un "id" tipo string " no auto-incremental ", que debería introducir en el modelo

Comment: @Rudy no, pero ten por seguro que si posteas la duda junto con una muestra de código para que quede clara tu pregunta, mas de uno de esta comunidad sabrá ayudarte